# Python: Filling out rows in text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file that is set up like below:

```
Category One
      1234X DD/MM/YYYY $1,234.56
      5678X DD/MM/YYYY $7,890.12
      9012X DD/MM/YYYY $3,456.78
Category One Total     $12,581.46
Category Two
      1234X DD/MM/YYYY $1,234.56
      5678X DD/MM/YYYY $7,890.12
      9012X DD/MM/YYYY $3,456.78
Category Two Total     $12,581.46
```

Using the code below. I can read all the lines and pull out specific lines that have a criteria in my key file.

```
keyfile = "keys.txt"
#this is the list of variables to pull from the test file
testfile = "test.txt"
#this is my original file obtained. The one that needs to be read and lines extracted from
testoutput = open('output.txt', 'w')
keys = [key for key in (line.strip() for line in open(keyfile)) if key]

with open(testfile) as f:
for line in f:
for key in keys:
    if key in line:
       testoutput.write(line)
```

However, I'd like to add the specific "Category" to each line so it would read like below.

```
Category One 1234X DD/MM/YYYY $1,234.56
Category One 5678X DD/MM/YYYY $7,890.12
Category One 9012X DD/MM/YYYY $3,456.78
Category Two 1234X DD/MM/YYYY $1,234.56
Category Two 5678X DD/MM/YYYY $7,890.12
Category Two 9012X DD/MM/YYYY $3,456.78
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what is keys.txt and what is test.txt?

Comment: Added edits. #this is the list of variables to pull from the test file
testfile = "test.txt"
#this is my original file obtained. The one that needs to be read and lines extracted from

Comment: #this? so test.txt is the first text file in your post and keywords are "Categorey One" etc? It's still not clear.